# Define Enunciate response of Map<String, String>

Tags: java, jax-rs, enunciate

The closest response data type description I can get is

```
map of object (JSON)
```

with a response example of

```
...
```

when I use the annotation

```
@TypeHint(Map.class)
```

---

Ideally I need to specify a response type of `Map<String, String>`, `HashMap<String, String>`, or something that would provide a response data type that makes sense and a response example similar to

```
{
    "...": "...",
    "...": "..."
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution using the `@requestExample` JavaDoc Tag detailed in the [Enunciate documentation](https://github.com/stoicflame/enunciate/wiki/Enunciate-Specific-Annotations#requestexample-javadoc-tag).

For example

```
@responseExample application/json {"..." : "..."}
```

Gives a proper response example of

```
{
  "...": "..."
}
```

Using the `@TypeHint(Object.class)` annotation produces a response data type of `object (JSON)`, which technically makes sense, so this solution is sufficient.